# Wordpress custom post type archive page wp_query pagination not working

Tags: pagination, custom-post-type, wordpress

I have created an archive page for my 'Event' custom post ape called archive-event.php.
I used the content from the standard archive.php template and it listed my 4 events in the order they were posted.

The next step was to change the order by the custom field event_date. I did this no problems. Then I wanted to not show any events that event_date had passed. The below code does this perfectly.

The issue I now have is my pagination is all messed up. I have the default reading settings set to 2 posts per page and I have a 'Load more' button to bring up the next two.

When I click 'Load more' it duplicates the two events already showing. Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

```
<?php 
$today = date("Ymd");
$args = array (
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'meta_key'       => 'event_date',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value', 
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'event_date',
                                'value' => $today,
                                'type' => 'numeric',
                                'compare' => '>=',
                                )
                            ),
                        );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $wp_query->have_posts() )
{
$wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

         <div>Content goes here</div>


<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Is your Load More button making an ajax call or are you using `next_posts_link()` or `posts_nav_link()` or some other method?

Comment: It is an ajax call. I disabled the plugin and went back to basic next/ later pagination and I still get the same issue so assume its nothing to do with the plugin. even when i clicked on previous posts it looped the current 2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how the plugin builds the UI it may or may not be respecting the [pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) functionality built into WordPress.

Try forcing the `paged` setting into your query like so:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array (
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'paged'          => $paged, // this will be set to what WordPress thinks is the proper page to start
    'meta_key'       => 'event_date',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value', 
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'event_date',
                                'value' => $today,
                                'type' => 'numeric',
                                'compare' => '>=',
                                )
                            ),
                        );
```

Next, if this still doesn't work, you can test the assumption that the `paged` parameter isn't working for some reason by changing the default `paged` value like so (again, just to test):

```
$paged = 2; // just force it to start on the second page to see if that works
```

If the above test works, I would say that `get_query_var()` believes you're on the first page.

Comment: Is it too early in our relationship to declare my love for you? The first suggestion worked. I was aware that by using wp_query it ignored other defaults but had no idea what it was.
Thank you so much

Comment: @user2272355 Ha, might be a bit early, yea. Have fun with the project!

Comment: For some reason, `get_query_var('paged')` on custom pages, but `get_query_var('page')` if you are using it on the front page